# WebDeploy fails after AppFabric 1.1 upgrade. ApplicationHost.config invalid attribute

Tags: iis, appfabric, webdeploy, applicationhost

We recently upgraded to AppFabric 1.1 and we are having some problems with the hosting services auto-start attributes when performing a web deploy.

IIS is functioning correctly with auto-start enabled on all the machines. The event log and IIS show no errors relating to incorrect configuration and I can access the web sites as expected. When going in to the WCF & WF Services Configuration the dialog displays correctly and Auto-Start is set to be enabled for all services. The application host for the virtual directory is also as expected with the following attributes included in the 'application' element:

```
serviceAutoStartEnabled="true"  serviceAutoStartProvider="Service"
serviceAutoStartMode="all"
```

So everything is working correctly and configuration is as expected. However when we attempt a `WebDeploy (msdeploy.exe)` to any of our applications (on all machines) we now receive:

```
Error: Unrecognized Attribute 'serviceAutoStartMode'
```

This is a showstopper for us as we have many machines that are updated with our deployment scripts and as it stands the only way we can deploy is by removing the three auto-start attributes shown above, deploy, and then re-enable. I know we can achieve this fairly easily using appcmd and have it as part of our scripts but this feels unnecessary.

Something must be wrong as this worked prior to the upgrade but I can't find any references on the web by others experiencing this or similar problems.

For the record the guest OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Same problem. This is annoying as hell.

Comment: Probably a hack on my part, but I opened up applicationhost.config and just removed the "serviceAutoStartMode="true"".  Make a backup of the file beforehand of course.  I had to run notepad (as administrator) as a side bar note.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but more a workaround for the time being.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <MachineName> {
    Import-Module ApplicationServer
    Set-ASApplication -SiteName <SiteName> -AutoStartMode Disable -VirtualPath <V.Path>
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName <MachineName> {
    Import-Module ApplicationServer
    Set-ASApplication -SiteName <SiteName> -AutoStartMode All -VirtualPath <V.Path>
}
```

Run the first command to disable the sites that use app fabric service auto start. Deploy, then re-enable it again.

This is probably a bug than an actual "feature"....